# Refreshing Azure Resource Graph queries in Azure workbook frequently gives missing data

Tags: azure-alerts, azure-resource-graph

I'm writing a Azure Resource Graph query in Azure workbook on Azure portal:

```
AlertsManagementResources 
| where type =~ 'microsoft.alertsmanagement/alerts'
| where properties.essentials.startDateTime > ago(30d)
| where properties.essentials.severity == "Sev0"
| extend State = tostring(properties.essentials.alertState)
| summarize count() by State
```

This query is giving me inconsistent results. Running the query gives me 50/50 chance of:

A. Retrieve all alerts from the last 30 days

B. Retrieve only recent alerts or no results at all.

What I have tried:

1. Check all the errors in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/troubleshoot/general but none of them fit my current situation
2. Running the query on Azure Resource Graph Explorer instead but still gives the same error so I think the problem is related to the Azure Resource Graph query, not the workbook.

P/S: Query Settings: Data source: "Azure Resource Graph"; Subscriptions: Any subscription with alerts fired 28-30 days ago; Visualization: "Grid"; Size: "Medium"

Comment: The scenario is not clear. Please stick to one scenario. Share enough details to reproduce the issue. If you get an error - share the error message. If there is no error, but the results are not what you expected - please explain why.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated my scenario. Please let me know if there's any specific details you are looking for to help identify my issue.

Comment: we'd have to see the exact error you are getting when it doesn't work.  ARG does have some pretty restrictive throttling limits on how many ARG queries you can run in a short period of time, are you getting errors like that?  i don't see any specific things in the query that jump out at me.  (though you might want to use a smaller time range?)

Comment: I'm not getting throttling error and have tried shortening the time period as well but it would still give me inconsistent results. I believe it has to do with how ARG handle the "AlertsManagementResources" table. I'm going to remove irrelevant tags to this question. Thank you for your insights!